# Is there a Regex to search for all arrays that are present in a project?

Tags: swift, regex, string

I am working on a large project in Xcode. I'm wanting to search, using the `Find Navigator` (See Below), for all arrays regardless of their name. I only care about any array that has this format, `someArray[index]`.

[image]

**Some Examples That Should Match**

- `people[12]`
- `section[0].rows[0]`

**Should Not Match**

- `people[index]`
- `section[section].row[row]`

The regex should only return arrays, it should not return any dictionaries or other types that are not a subscripted array.

Why am I doing this? Well, it appears there have been some issues within our app where devs have not properly handled index out of bounds errors or nil values. There are far too many arrays for me to manually go through line by line to find them, so this is the best option I've come up with and it may not even be possible. If anyone has other recommendations, please feel free to share.

Comment: I don't think you're going to have luck excluding other subscripts using this method, since the regex won't know the type of the subscript. For example, in `cars[index]`, the regex won't have a concept of whether `index` is an `Int` subscript for an array or a `String` key for a dictionary. Do you have a style guide that enforces a certain syntax for when the array is created? In other words `Array()` or `Array<>()` or `[]` or something like that?

Comment: @jnpdx at this point, any filtering of any type is better than manually looking through 13,000 results across 815 files lol. No style guide at all, basically default Swift.

Comment: @xTwisteDx try `\w+\[\w+]|\w+\[\w+\.\w+]`

Comment: I suggest you give an instructive example to illustrate what you want to match and what you don't want to match, showing your desired return value as a valid object and providing commentary you think would be helpful to readers. That way readers can test code against your example.

Comment: not sure if you can create a regex that would not match a dictionary subscript

Comment: @LeoDabus that get's me pretty close. Reduced it down to 1.4k instead of 18k.

Comment: we can make it require "index" or number if you want it more restrictive

Comment: It needs to be fairly open as there is no standard for what the variable name might be for the subscript. It could be a number, a variable, or something completely random.

Comment: In this case I think the regex above is the best you can get

Comment: @LeoDabus go ahead and post an answer and if no one comes up with anything better than that's what I'll stick with. It's certainly better than the options I've tried so far lol.

Comment: @xTwisteDx do you need a full match for `section[index].rows[row]`? As it is it would match `section[index]` and `rows[row]`

Comment: One or The Other for the match. I need it to be sure that it's not missing any 3D arrays.

Comment: `\w+\[\w+\.?\w*\]` a bit simpler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a regex to match any word followed by another word with optional period enclosed by brackets. Something like:

```
 \w+\[\w+(\.\w+)?\]
```

For more info about the regex above you can check this [link](https://regex101.com/r/eeIDxF/2)

[image]

For numbers only use \d+ instead:

```
\w+\[\d+\]
```

[image]
For more info about the regex above you can check this [link](https://regex101.com/r/maLxrn/1)

Comment: Can you actually add one where it's a [<number>], a real number, inside of the brackets? For example `[0]` `[12]` etc..? Any number.

Comment: the regex above should match them as well

Comment: I mean one without characters inside the bracket. ONLY digits. So you were right in your assumption it should be more restrictive.

Comment: check my last edit

Comment: Have a look at my edits to the question. I need it more restrictive. That current regex allows `array[index]` when it should only allow `array[0]`

Comment: Just use `d` instead of `w`